# What logs are kept about activity in a Guest Session in Ubuntu?

Tags: logging, guest-session

Recently, I learned a lot about the Guest Session, especially how to disable it. An intruder accessed my locked Ubuntu 14.04 laptop while I was away from my desk.

I can see where the Guest logged in and out in `/var/log/auth.log`. Is all activity logged or just the log in and log out?

The guest session was only 6 minutes, but would like to know what the intruder did, if anything.

Comment: I don't know to which extent activity during a guest session is logged outside of the temporary folder which was deleted at logout. OTOH no settings, neither system wide nor for regular users, can be changed from a guest session. That's by design.

Comment: @majickmann I deleted my post

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson...  I haven't found anything else other than the auth.log entries mentioned in my original post.  Hoping someone experienced with the logging functions of the "guest-session".  Doesn't seem to be documented, at least, I haven't found it.  For now, I'll presume the intruder logged on, found they could do little to nothing, and logged out.